# JQuery each() iteration - unexpected animation results

Tags: jquery, iteration, each, show

I have a series of 4 div's I would like to slide out from the right with about a 1 second delay between each animation starting. The problem I am having is that my use of .each() is not producing the effect I expected. Instead, the child div's of the container are all sliding out together at the same time. I have used a `alert( $( this ).text());` for testing inside of the `.each()` iteration and get the expected 4 alert boxes (First, Second, Third, Fourth). but placing the animation call `$(this).delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);` inside the `.each()` doesnt give me the expected iteration delay. Can someone point out what I have wrong here?

HTML

```
<div id="holder">
    <div style="display:none;">First</div>
    <div style="display:none;">Second</div>
    <div style="display:none;">Third</div>
    <div style="display:none;">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $( "#holder > div" ).each( function(){
        $(this).delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);    
        /*$( "#holder > div" ).each( function( index, element ){
        alert( $( this ).text() );*/
    }); 
});
```

CSS

```
#holder div {
    background-color:blue;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    color:white;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/8mrf8Luj/1/)

I also tried a `setTimeout();` inside the `.each()` call, but that also did not produce desired results and my review of the existing SO each/iteration questions didn't get me any further for the ones i reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `.each` loop to be like this

```
$( "#holder > div" ).each( function(index){
    $(this).delay(500*index).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

In [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) you can provide an optional `index` parameter in the handler function that will give you the index of the element you are on. (Beginning from 0)

In this case, you can use this to increase the delay based on the index of your elements, making them appear one after another.

Comment: Awesome, will accept when it lets me - can you point out JQuery DOCS location explaining the (index) variables role in this case?

Answer (score 0):

it's doing each one with the same delay, so to increase the delay each time you'd wanna do something like this.

```
var aniDelay = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#holder > div").each(function() {
    $(this).delay(500).show("slide", {
      direction: "right"
    }, aniDelay);
    aniDelay = aniDelay + 1000;
    /*$( "#holder > div" ).each( function( index, element ){
    alert( $( this ).text() );*/
  });
});
```